# Disable "Turn off hard disk after" in windows 7

Tags: windows-7, windows, hard-drive, power-management

How can I disable this feature? In the power options apparently I can only choose the minutes and I don't see a "Off" option. If I set it to 0 minutes, it sets itself to 1.

For now I set it to 20000000 minutes, but a real solution would be nice.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

There is a setting for *Never*.  You can either type it in or use the spin edit to go to the bottom most setting (It's right below 1 minute).

[image]

Comment: You can just type '0', that'll set it to 'Never'.

Comment: Setting does not appear to have any effect on W7x64. It's set to never and it still turns off.

Comment: @Overmind - I've used that setting on my w7x64 systems for many years and it has always worked.  Perhaps you have some other software installed that is turning off the hard disk?

Comment: I've check everything that is even slightly HDD related. Drives still power down and I keep hearing them re-powering up whenever I try to access something. I never had this problem at home, only on my system at work. There are 3 drives: one with OS, 2 in RAID 0; power-down happens to all of them when not too often accessed.

Comment: @Overmind Disable APM for disk on power on. What's the model of HDD?

Comment: Drives are older 500GB models: ST500DM002 and WD5000AAKX.