# SSD Fault causing BSOD

Tags: ssd, bsod

I built a computer for a friend with an OCZ petrol SSD.  It seems to be having some problems now.  Once or twice a day, it gets an error that looks like it's pointing to a disk sector and then blue screens.  I booted off System Rescue CD to try and take a backup image of the disk, but it failed with an error along the lines of being unable to read a segment.  The errors come totally at random, they don't seem to be associated with trying to read a certain file.  The variance in uptime between faults is pretty large.

I'd like to update the drive firmware at some stage, but first I want to have a full disk backup just in case anything goes wrong (took me a long time to get the computer correctly configured in the first place!).  What sort of tool will work to back up the disk, and is the problem likely to be solved by a firmware update or am I going to have to RMA the drive?

Comment: Do you have the error details?

Comment: I had a similar problem with a Mushkin Chronos SSD. The issue was solved with a firmware update so if there is a firmware update available for your ssd then definitely give it a go. Might be a good idea to trawl the OCZ forums for people with similar issues?

Comment: The errors usually don't last long enough to get any details from them unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a copy of the disk you can use `dd` to do it.

Simply boot up a linux live CD and enter this command

```
dd if=/dev/hdx | gzip > /path/to/image.gz
```

where hdx is your SSD and /path/to/image.gz is the location where you want to save the backup.

Answer (score 0):

I had issues with my new SSD (in a caching setup, though) where disabling power saving in Windows 7 did the job, the spin hdd setting to disabled as described in:

[Disable "Turn off hard disk after" in windows 7](https://superuser.com/questions/146696/disable-turn-off-hard-disk-after-in-windows-7)

No more BSODs and such things. I'm not sure if it consumes more power, since ssds don't spin up and down...

Comment: That's interesting, I'll be sure to do that once I get the current problem fixed!